# How to chose between transforming the data or applying a weighted regression when there is heteroscedasticity?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

For long I have seen advice that, when the assumption of homoscedasticity is violated, one should transform the data or use weighted least-squares ([see for example](https://www.statology.org/heteroscedasticity-regression/)). But the advice (at least the one I have gotten) is never clear as to when one method is superior to the other.

What are the criteria to choose between transforming the data or using weighted least-squares? When is it advisable to use one method and not the other?

Comment: Those are not the only two choices. You can also just use OLS and include robust standard errors or bootstrap. You can also try a different model that better explains the data (e.g., a model for positive values if all values are positive). The solution will depend on the unique features of the problem, so there is no general solution.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a particular application for which you need to make such choices? As @Noah says, "the solution will depend on the unique features of the problem." Often, the best way to learn the principles is to try to apply them to particular practical problems. You could edit the question to provide a situation you have in mind.

Comment: You can compare penalized likelihoods to see which model (WLS or transform) best fits the data. You have to be careful here to get the right likelihoods.